# Magento - Get Product options from $item

Tags: php, magento

On the cart page there's the following foreach loop:

```
foreach($this->getItems() as $_item) {

}
```

I need to get the product options for these items, I've tried a few methods but I'm unable to retrieve the results I need.

I've tried:

```
foreach($this->getItems() as $_item) {
    print_r($_item->getProductOptions());
}
```

And:

```
foreach($this->getItems() as $_item) {
    print_r($_item->getOptionList());
}
```

Are there any other functions I could use?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but if you're looking for a method, try: `var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($item)));` - you will get an array of all methods (not magic methods) of the class.

Comment: Very handy to know, thanks @StefanBrendle

Comment: @Karl: Add the type (that is the classname) to your question to improve it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started in the right direction...

```
$productSku = "ABCDE";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productId = $product->getIdBySku( $productSku );
$product->load($productId);

/**
 * In Magento Models or database schema level, the product's Custom Options are
 * executed & maintained as only "options". So, when checking whether any product has
 * Custom Options or not, we should check by using this method "hasOptions()" only.
 */
if($product->hasOptions()) {
    echo '<pre>';

    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
        $optionType = $o->getType();
        echo 'Type = '.$optionType;

        if ($optionType == 'drop_down') {
            $values = $o->getValues();

            foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                print_r($v);
            }
        }
        else {
            print_r($o);
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: getting blank in $product->hasOptions()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
foreach($items as $product) {
    $options = $product->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product->getProduct());
    if ($options)
    {
        if (isset($options['options']))
        {
            $result = $options['options'];
        }
        if(count($result)>0){
            foreach($result as $key =>$value){
                $resultoption =  $value['value'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current answer as it stands is a no-go for me. Whatever `$_item` is may not have the `getProduct()` method.

On the other hand, you will likely have an `id` available that you can load directly from. In my example, I needed to get the product object from an item in `$_items = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getItemCollection()`.

This enables me to use: `<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()) ?>`

Answer (score -7):

You can not get option list on cart.phtml, you have to update/edit below file for option list:

```
app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME\YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml
```

Hope it will help!