# Magento product with custom options do not merge qty in cart

Tags: php, magento

Whenever I add a product to cart with similar custom options, magento is creating a new item block instead of merging quantities in existing one with similar options. Below is the code I am using during checkout.

```
$product->addCustomOption('extra_options', serialize($extraOptions));
```

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here the link below help you to shortout your answer

[How to programmatically add a product with custom options to cart in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838558/how-to-programmatically-add-a-product-with-custom-options-to-cart-in-magento)

In above link answer will help you to add custom options